# JSFiddle to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I built a working template of an interactive google map in JSFiddle but when i try to piece it together to have one working file on my site it isn't loading the map portion.

I feel silly for asking this but I am very much an amateur - What order / headers etc do I need to do to put this site back together and have it functioning outside of jsfiddle?

here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kamelkid2/drytwvL8/114/

this was the logical flow how i tried to piece it together

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style type="text/css">
#map-canvas {
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>    

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

[javascript stuff] 
[html div portion]
```

this is my entire file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
#map-canvas {
    width: 700px;
    height: 500px;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var gmarkers1 = [];
var markers1 = [];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});

// Our markers
markers1 = [
    ['0', 'Cascade Park - 130 Lynn Dr, Hudson, OH 44236', 41.234830, -81.453479], //updated with guesses
    ['1', 'Solon Community Park - 33955 Sherbrook Park Dr, Solon, OH 44139', 41.402313, -81.437936], //updated with guesses
    ['2', 'Middleton Park - 1708 Middleton Rd, Hudson, OH 44236', 41.268963, -81.450649], //updated with guesses
    ['3', 'Silver Springs Park - 5027 Stow Rd Stow, OH 44224', 41.196766, -81.417072], //updated with guesses
    ['4', 'Liberty Park - 9385 Liberty Rd Twinsburg, OH 44087', 41.317218, -81.419225], //updated with guesses
    ['5', 'Sunny Lake Park - 885 E Mennonite Rd Aurora, OH 44202', 41.290323, -81.318730], //updated with guesses
    ['6', 'Aurora Premium Outlets - 549 S Chillicothe Rd, Aurora, OH 44202', 41.301904, -81.341941] //updated with guesses
];

var items = [
[1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
[1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1],
[1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0]
];

//[0] show marker
//[1] has playground
//[2] has baby swing 
//[3] has belt swing
//[4] has handicap swing
//[5] toddler friendly
//[6] RF ground
//[7] WC ground
//[8] Pavillion
//[9] Grill
//[10] ramps
//[11] restrooms
//[12] close restrooms
//[13] nursing station
//[14] changing table
//[15] stroller friendly
//[16] walking trails

/**
 * Function to init map
 */

function initialize() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(41.334830, -81.453479);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        addMarker(markers1[i]);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to add marker to map
 */

function addMarker(marker) {
    var title = marker[1];
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(marker[2], marker[3]);
    var content = marker[1];

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        title: title,
        position: pos,
        map: map
    });

    gmarkers1.push(marker1);

    // Marker click listener
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', (function (marker1, content) {
        return function () {
            console.log('Gmarker 1 gets pushed');
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map, marker1);
            map.panTo(this.getPosition());
        }
    })(marker1, content));
}

/**
 * Function to filter markers by category
 */


filterMarkersPG = function (categorypg) {

        //set all to view
        for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
        items[i][0] = 1;
        marker = gmarkers1[i];
        marker.setVisible(true);
        //window.alert("setting all to yes");
    }

        //import checkbox values
        var PlaygroundCheck = document.getElementById("playground").checked;
    var BabySwingCheck = document.getElementById("babyswing").checked;
    var BeltSwingCheck = document.getElementById("beltswing").checked;
    var HandicapSwingCheck = document.getElementById("handicapswing").checked;
    var ToddlerFriendlyCheck = document.getElementById("toddlerfriendly").checked;
    var RFGroundCheck = document.getElementById("rfground").checked;
    var WCGroundCheck = document.getElementById("wcground").checked;
    var PavillionCheck = document.getElementById("pavillion").checked;
    var GrillCheck = document.getElementById("grill").checked;
    var RampsCheck = document.getElementById("ramps").checked;
    var RestroomsCheck = document.getElementById("restrooms").checked;
    var CloseRestroomsCheck = document.getElementById("closerestrooms").checked;
    var NursingStationCheck = document.getElementById("nursingstation").checked;
    var ChangingTableCheck = document.getElementById("changingtable").checked;
    var StrollerFriendlyCheck = document.getElementById("strollerfriendly").checked;
    var WalkingTrailsCheck = document.getElementById("walkingtrails").checked;

    //test that it still works
    //window.alert(PlaygroundCheck);
    //window.alert(BabySwingCheck);

    //test if playground checkbox is checked
    if (PlaygroundCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through playground marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get playground binary
            HasPlayground = items[i][1];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has a playground
            if (HasPlayground == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of playground check


    //test if babyswing checkbox is checked
    if (BabySwingCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through babyswing marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get babyswing binary
            HasBabySwing = items[i][2];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has a babyswing
            if (HasBabySwing == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of baby swing test


    //test if beltswing checkbox is checked
    if (BeltSwingCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through babyswing marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get beltswing binary
            HasBeltSwing = items[i][3];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has a beltswing
            if (HasBeltSwing == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of belt swing test

    //test if handicapswing checkbox is checked
    if (HandicapSwingCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through babyswing marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get handicapswing binary
            HasHandicapSwing = items[i][4];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has a handicapswing
            if (HasHandicapSwing == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of handicap swing test

    //test if toddlerfriendly checkbox is checked
    if (ToddlerFriendlyCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through babyswing marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get handicapswing binary
            HasToddlerFriendly = items[i][5];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has a handicapswing
            if (HasToddlerFriendly == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of ToddlerFriendly swing test

    //test if rf ground checkbox is checked
    if (RFGroundCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasRFGround = items[i][6];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasRFGround == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of RFGround test

    //test if wc ground checkbox is checked
    if (WCGroundCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasWCGround = items[i][7];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasWCGround == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of WCGround test

    //test if pavillion checkbox is checked
    if (PavillionCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasPavillion = items[i][8];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasPavillion == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of pavillion test

     //test if grill checkbox is checked
    if (GrillCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasGrill = items[i][9];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasGrill == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of grill test

     //test if ramp checkbox is checked
    if (RampsCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasRamps = items[i][10];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasRamps == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of ramps test

     //test if restrooms checkbox is checked
    if (RestroomsCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasRestrooms = items[i][11];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasRestrooms == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of restrooms test

     //test if close restrooms checkbox is checked
    if (CloseRestroomsCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasCloseRestrooms = items[i][12];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasCloseRestrooms == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of close restrooms test

    //test if nursingstation checkbox is checked
    if (NursingStationCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasRamps = items[i][13];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasRamps == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of ramps test

    //test if changing table checkbox is checked
    if (ChangingTableCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasChangingTable = items[i][14];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasChangingTable == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of changing table test

    //test if stroller friendly checkbox is checked
    if (StrollerFriendlyCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasStrollerFriendly = items[i][15];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasStrollerFriendly == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of changing table test

    //test if walking trails checkbox is checked
    if (WalkingTrailsCheck == true) {    

            //for all sites, loop through marker
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

            //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
            if (items[i][0] == 1){

            //get binary
            HasWalkingTrails = items[i][16];
            marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has it
            if (HasWalkingTrails == 1){
                    //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
            else {
                    //set the marker to false
                marker.setVisible(false);

                //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                items[i][0] = 0;

            }

            }

        }

    } //end of walking Trails test


}


// Init map
initialize();
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<br>
<table>

<tr><u>Required Items (Select All That Apply):</u></tr><br>

<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='playground' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Playground</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='toddlerfriendly' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Toddler Friendly</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='grill' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Grill</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='nursingstation' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Nursing Station</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='babyswing' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Baby Swings</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='rfground' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Rubber Flooring</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='ramps' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Ramps</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='changingtable' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Changing Table</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='beltswing' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Belt Swings</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='wcground' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Wood Chips Flooring</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='restrooms' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Restrooms</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='strollerfriendly' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Stroller Friendly</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='handicapswing' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Handicap Swings</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='pavillion' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Pavillion</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='closerestrooms' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Close Restrooms</td>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='walkingtrails' onclick="filterMarkersPG(this.value);">Has Walking Trails</td>
</tr>

</table>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. i am still struggling though. could you please advise on what i am still doing wrong? this is the order i have placed things

<html tag>
<css>
<start head>
[js stuff]
<end head>
<start body>
[html stuff]
<end body>
<end html>

Comment: i have also tried in the body tag but it is still not loading. the checkboxes load (as it does with all my other trials), but just no map

Comment: I think you just have to put your initializing stuff inside a `window.onload = function () { /* your init stuff here*/}` -  normally on top of your custom javascript. jsFiddle puts the javascript by default inside this handler.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

i reworked it outside of jsfiddle and i got it to work. i handled things slightly differently. i suspect i had a syntax error somewhere or loaded things out of order.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
    <head> 
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
      <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
              type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head> 
    <body>
      <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 500px;"></div>

      <script type="text/javascript">

        var markers1 = [
          ['Cascade Park - 130 Lynn Dr, Hudson, OH 44236', 41.234830, -81.453479, 1],
          ['Solon Community Park - 33955 Sherbrook Park Dr, Solon, OH 44139', 41.402313, -81.437936, 2],
          ['Middleton Park - 1708 Middleton Rd, Hudson, OH 44236', 41.268963, -81.450649, 3],
          ['Silver Springs Park - 5027 Stow Rd Stow, OH 44224', 41.196766, -81.417072, 4],
          ['Liberty Park - 9385 Liberty Rd Twinsburg, OH 44087', 41.317218, -81.419225, 5],
          ['Sunny Lake Park - 885 E Mennonite Rd Aurora, OH 44202', 41.290323, -81.318730, 6], 
          ['Aurora Premium Outlets - 549 S Chillicothe Rd, Aurora, OH 44202', 41.301904, -81.341941, 7] 
        ];

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.334830, -81.453479),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, i;
        var gmarkers1 = [];

        for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers1[i][1], markers1[i][2]),
            map: map
          });

        gmarkers1.push(marker);  

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(markers1[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }


        var items = [
        [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0]
        ];

        //[0] show marker
        //[1] has playground
        //[2] has baby swing 
        //[3] has belt swing
        //[4] has handicap swing
        //[5] toddler friendly
        //[6] RF ground
        //[7] WC ground
        //[8] Pavillion
        //[9] Grill
        //[10] ramps
        //[11] restrooms
        //[12] close restrooms
        //[13] nursing station
        //[14] changing table
        //[15] stroller friendly
        //[16] walking trails

        function ToggleMarker(a){

            //set all to view
            for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {
                items[i][0] = 1;
                marker = gmarkers1[i];
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }

            //import checkbox values
            var PlaygroundCheck = document.getElementById("playground").checked;
            var BabySwingCheck = document.getElementById("babyswing").checked;
            var BeltSwingCheck = document.getElementById("beltswing").checked;
            var HandicapSwingCheck = document.getElementById("handicapswing").checked;
            var ToddlerFriendlyCheck = document.getElementById("toddlerfriendly").checked;
            var RFGroundCheck = document.getElementById("rfground").checked;
            var WCGroundCheck = document.getElementById("wcground").checked;
            var PavillionCheck = document.getElementById("pavillion").checked;
            var GrillCheck = document.getElementById("grill").checked;
            var RampsCheck = document.getElementById("ramps").checked;
            var RestroomsCheck = document.getElementById("restrooms").checked;
            var CloseRestroomsCheck = document.getElementById("closerestrooms").checked;
            var NursingStationCheck = document.getElementById("nursingstation").checked;
            var ChangingTableCheck = document.getElementById("changingtable").checked;
            var StrollerFriendlyCheck = document.getElementById("strollerfriendly").checked;
            var WalkingTrailsCheck = document.getElementById("walkingtrails").checked;

            //test that it still works
            //window.alert(PlaygroundCheck);
            //window.alert(BabySwingCheck);

            //test if playground checkbox is checked
            if (PlaygroundCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through playground marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                    //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                    if (items[i][0] == 1){

                        //get playground binary
                        HasPlayground = items[i][1];
                        marker = gmarkers1[i];
                        //test if it has a playground

                        if (HasPlayground == 1){
                            //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                            marker.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        else {
                            //set the marker to false
                            marker.setVisible(false);

                            //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                            items[i][0] = 0;

                        }

                    }

                }

            } //end of playground check

            //test if babyswing checkbox is checked
            if (BabySwingCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through babyswing marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                    //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                    if (items[i][0] == 1){

                        //get babyswing binary
                        HasBabySwing = items[i][2];
                        marker = gmarkers1[i];

                        //test if it has a babyswing
                        if (HasBabySwing == 1){
                            //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                            marker.setVisible(true);
                        }
                        else {
                                //set the marker to false
                            marker.setVisible(false);

                            //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                            items[i][0] = 0;

                        }

                    }

                }

            } //end of baby swing test


        //test if beltswing checkbox is checked
        if (BeltSwingCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through babyswing marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get beltswing binary
                HasBeltSwing = items[i][3];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has a beltswing
                if (HasBeltSwing == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of belt swing test

        //test if handicapswing checkbox is checked
        if (HandicapSwingCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through babyswing marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get handicapswing binary
                HasHandicapSwing = items[i][4];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has a handicapswing
                if (HasHandicapSwing == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of handicap swing test

        //test if toddlerfriendly checkbox is checked
        if (ToddlerFriendlyCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through babyswing marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get handicapswing binary
                HasToddlerFriendly = items[i][5];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has a handicapswing
                if (HasToddlerFriendly == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of ToddlerFriendly swing test

        //test if rf ground checkbox is checked
        if (RFGroundCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasRFGround = items[i][6];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasRFGround == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of RFGround test

        //test if wc ground checkbox is checked
        if (WCGroundCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasWCGround = items[i][7];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasWCGround == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of WCGround test

        //test if pavillion checkbox is checked
        if (PavillionCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasPavillion = items[i][8];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasPavillion == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of pavillion test

         //test if grill checkbox is checked
        if (GrillCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasGrill = items[i][9];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasGrill == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of grill test

         //test if ramp checkbox is checked
        if (RampsCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasRamps = items[i][10];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasRamps == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of ramps test

         //test if restrooms checkbox is checked
        if (RestroomsCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasRestrooms = items[i][11];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasRestrooms == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of restrooms test

         //test if close restrooms checkbox is checked
        if (CloseRestroomsCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasCloseRestrooms = items[i][12];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasCloseRestrooms == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of close restrooms test

        //test if nursingstation checkbox is checked
        if (NursingStationCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasRamps = items[i][13];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasRamps == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of ramps test

        //test if changing table checkbox is checked
        if (ChangingTableCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasChangingTable = items[i][14];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasChangingTable == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of changing table test

        //test if stroller friendly checkbox is checked
        if (StrollerFriendlyCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasStrollerFriendly = items[i][15];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasStrollerFriendly == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of changing table test

        //test if walking trails checkbox is checked
        if (WalkingTrailsCheck == true) {    

                //for all sites, loop through marker
                for (i = 0; i < markers1.length; i++) {  

                //if it is still enabled (we dont want to reenable a previously disabled)
                if (items[i][0] == 1){

                //get binary
                HasWalkingTrails = items[i][16];
                marker = gmarkers1[i];

                            //test if it has it
                if (HasWalkingTrails == 1){
                        //set the marker to true (probably redundant)
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
                else {
                        //set the marker to false
                    marker.setVisible(false);

                    //prevent it from being viewed again in the loop
                    items[i][0] = 0;

                }

                }

            }

        } //end of walking Trails test

        }




      </script>
      <br>
    <table>

    <tr><u>Required Items (Select All That Apply):</u></tr><br>

    <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='playground' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Playground</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='toddlerfriendly' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Toddler Friendly</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='grill' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Grill</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='nursingstation' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Nursing Station</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='babyswing' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Baby Swings</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='rfground' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Rubber Flooring</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='ramps' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Ramps</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='changingtable' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Changing Table</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='beltswing' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Belt Swings</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='wcground' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Wood Chips Flooring</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='restrooms' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Restrooms</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='strollerfriendly' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Stroller Friendly</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='handicapswing' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Handicap Swings</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='pavillion' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Pavillion</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='closerestrooms' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Close Restrooms</td>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='walkingtrails' onclick="ToggleMarker(this.value);">Has Walking Trails</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```